# Google Spreadsheet limit ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I'm using the `ArrayFormula` to calculate multiple ranges and it's slow because it's trying to calculate everything in that range, even though it has nothing in it.

Is there a way I can limit the `ArrayFormula` to only calculate a certain amount of rows in a range?

Comment: Can you show as at least the formula ?

Answer (score 1):

If your are using as a parameter a range that is too large, i.e. whole columns references like A:A, but you don't require the whole range, change it to a smaller range like A1:10. Also you could use functions like FILTER, QUERY, OFFSET, among others, to return small enough ranges.